# Grid swap rows and save new order to mysql - Using php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am currently using a javascript table script called tableFilter, which works for the purpose I originally needed which was simply displaying data with the ability to filter and sort. Now I need one more function which is the ability to swap rows and save the new order to the mysql table. For example if the table is books, and the list of books is shown with a column rank and the grid is sorted on rank, if the user swaps 2 rows I want the new rank of the swapped rows to get saved to the mysql table. I looked a jqGrid and I like the look and functionality of the grid, but I do not see how they would change the rank in the grid and then save it to the database. Can someone direct me in the right direction towards a script or idea for this?

Comment: I would like to add that after investigation, I decided to go with TableDND which can be found here :[TableDND](http://isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/)  ... it is a lightweight jquery plugin and does what I needed and I was able to use it along with the tablefilter js script that I am using as well. I originally asked for a script to swap rows, but after thinking it through, what I really needed was a script to move a row in a table. This does just that.

I highly recommend it for anyone looking for a simple way to drag and drop rows in a table

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look for the JS plugin which allows using callback function after some user actions. 
Usually, it's called something like "onSuccess" or "afterSort" and is specified in the grid-plugin documentation you're going to use.

For example, after you sort data in table, plugin will execute *your* function. In this function you will need to set up an AJAX request your script which will insert some data into your database.

Unfortunately i can't recommend some plugin to you as i don't really use anything like this.